# Automapper - v5.2.0 Nullsubstitute String working with Map but not with ProjectTo

Tags: string, automapper, projection

I tried to use AutoMapper NullSubstitute feature with source member and destination member of type string.

It doesn't seem to work with Projection.

As an example, I adapted [src/UnitTests/Projection/NullSubstitutes.cs](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/blob/master/src/UnitTests/Projection/NullSubstitutes.cs).

```
namespace AutoMapper.UnitTests.Projection
{
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using QueryableExtensions;

    using Xunit;

    public class NullSubstitutesWithMapFrom
    {
        private List<Dest> _dests;

        public class Source
        {
            public string Value { get; set; }
        }

        public class Dest
        {
            public string ValuePropertyNotMatching { get; set; }
        }

        [Fact]
        public void Can_substitute_null_values()
        {
            MapperConfiguration Configuration = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
          {
              cfg.CreateMap<Source, Dest>().ForMember(m => m.ValuePropertyNotMatching, opt =>
              {
                  opt.MapFrom(src => src.Value);
                  opt.NullSubstitute("5");
              });

          });

            var source = new[] { new Source { Value = null } }.AsQueryable();
            _dests = source.ProjectTo<Dest>(Configuration).ToList();

            Assert.Equal("5", _dests[0].ValuePropertyNotMatching);
        }
    }
}
```

Expected : "5" equals "5"
Actual : "5" equals null

With Map everything is ok

```
namespace AutoMapper.UnitTests.Projection
{
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;

    using Xunit;

    public class NullSubstitutesWithMapFrom
    {
        private List<Dest> _dests;

        public class Source
        {
            public string Value { get; set; }
        }

        public class Dest
        {
            public string ValuePropertyNotMatching { get; set; }
        }

        [Fact]
        public void Can_substitute_null_values()
        {
            MapperConfiguration Configuration = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
          {
              cfg.CreateMap<Source, Dest>().ForMember(m => m.ValuePropertyNotMatching, opt =>
              {
                  opt.MapFrom(src => src.Value);
                  opt.NullSubstitute("5");
              });

          });

            var source = new[] { new Source { Value = null } }.ToList();
            _dests = Configuration.CreateMapper().Map<List<Dest>>(source);
            Assert.Equal("5", _dests[0].ValuePropertyNotMatching);


        }
    }
}
```

It looks a bit like what was described in https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/issues/642

Comment: Move the null check inside the `MapFrom`. I'm not sure why, but for `ProjectTo`, the `NullSubstitute` only applies for `Nullable`.

Comment: Thanks for the advice @LucianBargaoanu. I already did it actually and it works.
But accordiing to some digging, it should work.
I've seen a couple of examples with objets.

Comment: Let's say it's an entity type, not string. What would you put as null substitute? Try that in a EF linq query, without AM.

Comment: I get your point and it's true that all the examples that I've seen are using Map and not ProjectTo.
e.g : 
- https://weblogs.asp.net/psteele/automapper-handling-null-members
- https://dotnettutorials.net/lesson/usevalue-resolveusing-and-null-substitution-using-automapper/

Do you know if it has always been like that for ProjecTo, Nullsubstitute and string ?
Have you heard about a fix planned for some day?

Comment: https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/pull/3438/commits/26293ad5b3d3568b15cfddd210eb5b335ffbd98a

Comment: Thank you. I subscribed to the Merge Request.